# Storyboard Vs Simulator no constraint apply

Tags: ios, uiimageview, constraints, xcode9

most likely I'm doing a lot of confusion after so many hours of work but I do not understand what's going on ...

In the photo that I show you below you can see the storyboard lamm. The orange arrow indicates that I'm working on iPhone SE while my simulators are iPhone SE and IPhone 8 plus ..

As you can see, the two simulators have two different views even though I've put constraints.
[image]

[image]

UIImageView has a gradient effect on it, if I take UIImageView to look perfectly on all devices even though I'm working on the storyboard Iphone I .. I do not understand why this can help me?

I also show you the UIImageView code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
CAGradientLayer *gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientMask.frame = _images.bounds;
gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];

_images.layer.mask = gradientMask;

gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.8, 0.0);
gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.8, 0.8);

gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
gradientMask.locations = @[@0.0, @0.0, @0.8, @1.0];

_images.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

UIBlurEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *blur = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
blur.frame = CGRectMake(_images.frame.origin.x, _images.frame.origin.y, _images.frame.size.width, _images.frame.size.height +50);
[_images addSubview:blur];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.1 animations:^{
    blur.alpha = .7;
}];
```

}

Comment: you should show also the constraints, seems like those are the problem

Comment: Just me or u just set the height and width instead of placing anchors on the sides?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ i edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling:

```
gradientMask.frame = _images.bounds;
```

in `viewDidLoad()`. At that point, auto-layout has not yet laid-out all the views, so your `_images.bounds` matches what you have in your Storyboard.

The result is that the right-side of the image view is *masked out* because the gradient layer isn't covering it.

You need to either move the gradient mask creation / sizing to a point *after* auto-layout is finished, or, what I'd recommend, is subclassing `UIImageView` to add the gradient mask there, and have it auto-resize it in `layoutSubviews()`.

Edit: as a side note, you should not put view animations in `viewDidLoad()` - most likely you won't even see it.

Comment: In fact the problem was just this !! Thanks a lot ... I would still need a little help with my uicollectionview .. the cells do not respond correctly to the collectionView Flow layout impulses between the various devices, i think it's always a constraint problem .. i just see it iphone SE how can I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

try this ....

1.first select which phone u need ,if u need iPhone 8 then select the simulator iPhone 8 and below of the MainStoryboard there is a option to select the phone its orientation then select the view iPhone 8.
2.place the image in ViewController 
3.then in side of the Xcode select the image and then autoresizing option select the horizontal and vertical line(tick on that).

then run u will get the correct view.